# How to publish a shadow jar with an empty pom using gradle maven-publish plugin and Kotlin DSL?

Tags: java, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, shadowjar

The shadow plugin documentation has an [example for groovy](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/publishing/) but I do not understand how to translate this to Kotlin.

Groovy example from https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/publishing :

```
publishing {
  publications {
    shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
      project.shadow.component(publication)
    }
  }
}
```

My best attempt at the Kotlin version:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("pluginMaven") {
      artifact(tasks["shadowJar"])
      project.shadow.component(this)
    }
  }
}
```

With the above Kotlin version, shadowed dependencies **show up in the resulting pom as runtime dependencies**, which defies of purpose of shadowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
tasks {
    shadowJar {
       archiveClassifier.set("")
        minimize()
    }
}
```

Some background in [this github issue](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/598).